# How to override `--prefix` option in NASM per symbol?

Tags: c, gcc, nasm, name-mangling, linker-scripts

I'm compiling C code with GCC and assembling some x86 code with NASM on Windows.

Now, GCC by default (and I haven't been able to find an option to change this) prepends an underscore `_` to all external symbol names (and expected names).

I need this assembly code to work with GCC on both Windows and Linux and would like to avoid hacks as much as possible (and code duplication; I had separate `.s` files for Windows/Linux at first).

I found out about (and used) the `--prefix` flag in NASM. Now for some symbols I'd like NASM to treat them as *without* the leading underscore (exact situation right now is that I need to reference the entry point in a linker script without the leading underscore). Hence the question here on how to override, per symbol, the `--prefix`/`--postfix` flags of NASM.

Feel free to treat this as an XY problem. If there's a way to set the mangling scheme of GCC for C that'd be great, for example.

Comment: Regarding "Feel free to treat this as an XY problem.". I am curious based on some of the details whether you are doing this to build an Operating System?

Comment: @MichaelPetch - Indeed :D I'm working through the [Little OS Book](http://littleosbook.github.io/) with others and we'd prefer to have the same code compile on both Windows and Linux for as long as we can.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem. I've created an include file with a lot of defines like

```
%define printf  _printf
%define puts    _puts
%define scanf   _scanf
```

and some other stuff.

That file (libc_win32.in) is included by a "master" include file (libc.inc):

```
%ifndef LIBC_INC
%define LIBC_INC

%ifdef win32
    %include 'libc_win32.inc'
%elifdef win64
    %include 'libc_win64.inc'
%elifdef elf32
    %include 'libc_elf32.inc'
%elifdef elf64
    %include 'libc_elf64.inc'
%else
;   %error "libc.inc"
%endif

%endif
```

I set the symbols and include the files at the command line:

```
nasm -fwin32 -dwin32 -plibc.inc ...
```

or

```
nasm -felf32 -delf32 -plibc.inc ...
```

There is a predefined macro called `__OUTPUT_FORMAT__`, but it works only inside of a macro, not at program start.